# matching passwords with react hooks is not working after onchange

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hooks, passwords

I'm trying change error state after two password states become equal. But when I finish typing passwords onchange doesn't execute it requires to execute one more time.

*on using onkeyup events It works but i dont if its a good practice or not.
I've also tried making it a timeout function but it didn't help either

Here are my functions.

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const [password2, setPassword2] = useState('')
const [passError, setPerror] = useState(false)

const handleChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    console.log(name +"  "+ value);
    

    if(name == 'username') setUsername(value);
    if(name == 'email') setEmail(value);
    if(name == 'pass') setPassword(value);
    if(name == 'pass2') setPassword2(value);

    setTimeout(()=>checkPass(), 2000);
    
}

const checkPass = () => {
    if (password != password2) setPerror(true);
    else setPerror(false);
    console.log(passError)
}
```

Here is my html.

```
<input type="password" className="form-control" name="pass"  placeholder="Password" required=""  
        value={password}  onChange={handleChange} onKeyUp={handleChange} style={{marginBottom: 0}} />      

        <input type="password" className="form-control" name="pass2"  placeholder="Confirm Password" required=""
        value={password2}  onChange={handleChange} />  

        { passError && <p className='alert-danger'>Password does not match!</p>}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that you are attempting to reference state that hasn't updated yet. It actually doesn't matter how long the timeout you set is, the "instance" of `checkPass` with the unupdated state is what is enqueued and closed over in the callback scope. It will always and forever be the state value *at the time* the callback was enqueued.

## Solution

Instead of using a timeout to check the state after it updates, use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the password state values to call `checkPass` and do the validation. Similarly move the logging of the `passError` state to an `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  checkPass();
}, [password, password2]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(passError);
}, [passError]);

const handleChange = (event) => {
  const { checked, name, type, value } = event.target;
  const newValue = type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value;

  if (name === 'username') setUsername(newValue);
  if (name === 'email') setEmail(newValue);
  if (name === 'pass') setPassword(newValue);
  if (name === 'pass2') setPassword2(newValue);
}

const checkPass = () => setPerror(password !== password2);
```